Kinova Gen3 7dof arm control in ROS kinetic
I'm trying to attach a Kinova Gen3 7dof arm to a 4-wheeled robot.
I got the files for the arm from this repository: https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/ros_kortex/tree/kinetic-devel
Anyways, I was able to load the arm's xacro file into the 4-wheeled robot file.
Now I'm attempting to establish a connection for its controller (want to move the arm in RViz).
I've launched an edited spawn_kortex_robot.launch (as seen below) file from the package, "kortex_gazebo."
<!-- Arguments -->
<!-- Start the GUIs -->
<arg name="start_gazebo" default="false"/>
<arg name="gazebo_gui"   default ="true"/>
<arg name="start_rviz" default="true"/>

<!-- Initial position in Gazebo -->
<arg name="x0" default="0"/>
<arg name="y0" default="0"/>
<arg name="z0" default="0"/>

<!-- Arm type -->
<arg name="arm" default="gen3"/>
<arg name="dof" default="7" if="$(eval arg('arm') == 'gen3')"/> <!-- Number of degrees of freedom of the arm -->
<arg name="dof" default="6" if="$(eval arg('arm') == 'gen3_lite')"/> <!-- Number of degrees of freedom of the arm -->
<arg name="vision" default="true"/> <!-- True if the arm has a Vision module -->

<!-- Default gripper for Gen3 is none, default gripper for Gen3 lite is gen3_lite_2f -->
<arg name="gripper" default="" if="$(eval arg('arm') == 'gen3')"/>
<arg name="gripper" default="gen3_lite_2f" if="$(eval arg('arm') == 'gen3_lite')"/>

<arg name="robot_name" default="my_$(arg arm)"/>
<arg name="prefix" default="arm_"/>
<arg name="cyclic_data_publish_rate" default="40"/>

    <!-- Delay before homing the arm -->
<arg name="start_delay_seconds" default="10"/>

<group ns="$(arg robot_name)">

 <!-- Start the trajectory controllers -->

    <!-- Without gripper -->
    <node name="$(arg prefix)$(arg arm)_trajectory_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
        output="screen" args="$(arg prefix)$(arg arm)_joint_trajectory_controller $(arg prefix)joint_state_controller"
        if="$(eval not arg('gripper'))"/>

    <!-- With gripper -->
    <node name="$(arg prefix)$(arg arm)_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
        output="screen" args="$(arg prefix)$(arg arm)_joint_trajectory_controller $(arg prefix)joint_state_controller $(arg prefix)$(arg gripper)_gripper_controller"
        unless="$(eval not arg('gripper'))"/>

    <!-- Individual position controllers are stopped at first -->

    <!-- For 6 DOF arms -->
    <node name="$(arg prefix)$(arg arm)_position_controllers_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
        output="screen" if="$(eval arg('dof') == 6)" args=" --stopped
        $(arg prefix)joint_1_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_2_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_3_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_4_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_5_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_6_position_controller"/>
    <!-- For 7 DOF arms -->
    <node name="$(arg prefix)$(arg arm)_position_controllers_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
        output="screen" if="$(eval arg('dof') == 7)" args=" --stopped
        $(arg prefix)joint_1_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_2_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_3_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_4_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_5_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_6_position_controller
        $(arg prefix)joint_7_position_controller"/>

    <!-- Start simulated Kortex Driver -->
    <node name="$(arg robot_name)_driver" pkg="kortex_driver" type="kortex_arm_driver" output="screen"> <!--launch-prefix="gdb -ex run args"-->
        <param name="sim" value="true"/>
        <param name="cyclic_data_publish_rate" value="$(arg cyclic_data_publish_rate)"/>
        <param name="arm" value="$(arg arm)"/>
        <param name="gripper" value="$(arg gripper)"/>
        <param name="dof" value="$(arg dof)"/>
        <param name="robot_name" value="$(arg robot_name)"/>
        <param name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find kortex_description)/arms/$(arg arm)/$(arg dof)dof/config/joint_limits.yaml" subst_value="true"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find kortex_description)/arms/$(arg arm)/$(arg dof)dof/config/twist_limits.yaml" subst_value="true"/>
        <!-- If there is a gripper, load the active joint names for it -->
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find kortex_description)/grippers/$(arg gripper)/config/joint_limits.yaml" unless="$(eval not arg('gripper'))" subst_value="true"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Start robot state publisher -->
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen" />

    <!-- Start MoveIt main executable -->
    <!-- TODO Find cleaner way to do that and that will work with other arms -->
    <!-- Without gripper -->
    <include file="$(find kortex_description)/../kortex_move_it_config/$(arg arm)_move_it_config/launch/move_group.launch" if="$(eval not arg('gripper'))"> 
        <arg name="dof" value="$(arg dof)"/>
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
    </include>
    <!-- With gripper -->
    <include file="$(find kortex_description)/../kortex_move_it_config/$(arg arm)_$(arg gripper)_move_it_config/launch/move_group.launch" unless="$(eval not arg('gripper'))">
        <arg name="dof" value="$(arg dof)"/>
        <arg name="prefix" value="$(arg prefix)"/>
    </include>

    <!-- Sleep, then unpause the physics in Gazebo and home the robot -->
    <node name="home_the_arm" pkg="kortex_gazebo" type="home_robot.py" output="screen" respawn="false" launch-prefix="bash -c 'sleep $(arg start_delay_seconds); $0 $@'">
        <param name="robot_name" value="$(arg robot_name)"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Test if homing the robot with MoveIt ended correctly -->
    <test test-name="paramtest_gazebo_initialization" pkg="rostest" type="paramtest">
        <param name="param_name_target" value="is_initialized" />
        <param name="param_value_expected" value="true" />
        <param name="wait_time" value="60" />
    </test> 

    <!-- Start RViz -->
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" if="$(arg start_rviz)"/> 

</group>

This is giving me this warning and error in the terminal.
[ WARN] [1722954693.902701317, 20.870000000]: Waiting for arm_gen3_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1722954710.411431630, 26.874000000]: Action client not connected: arm_gen3_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
The robot loads in gazebo and RViz is up. Only thing is I can't control the arm.
Any help would be appreciated!
